# Can SVC give different results? [scikit-learn v0.14]

Tags: svm, scikit-learn

I'm noticing that given the same feature table (training data) and feature vector for an [SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html), I am getting different results for the predict_proba output.

Is this expected behavior for an SVC or should I be getting consistent results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is caused by the fact that libsvm is calibrating probabilities using cross-validation on random folds of the dataset. In recent versions of sklearn (0.14.1+), passing the `random_state=0` as constructor param should fix the PRNG seed used internally by libsvm. If it does not fix the outcome, please feel free to open github issue with a minimalistic reproduction script.

Comment: Thanks very much for this explanation. When I check for my sci-kit learn version, >>> import sklearn, >>> sklearn.__version__, '0.13-git'. Is this version recent enough for the random_state=0? Do you happen to know of a way to upgrade to the latest release?

Comment: I tested it with random_state=0 and it gives consistent results. Thanks for your quick and correct answer!

Comment: 0.13-git means some times between the 0.12 release and the 0.13 release. You should definitely pull the latest master on regular basis or use stable releases.